# I am unsure how to execute and interpret a simple linear regression model where Y ~ a single X

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, excel

I have the following table of X and Y values:

```
   X     Y
1    68   55
2    54   38
3    90  95
4    64  63
5    61  58
6    51  40
7    79  74
8    51  32
9    83  84 
10  48  45
```

I have to do the following:

- Make linear regression using the method of least squares
- Draw some conclusions from this model when X = 100
- Calculate the standard error for the model

Comment: X1=68 Y1= 55 X2=54 Y2= 38 etc...

Comment: My first question, would be, what tool would you prefer to use to do a linear regression? Would love to help with a solution that can show you how to do it vs just doing it for you (which I don't think will help in the long run).

Comment: Dear Nathaniel, actually i have no idea what is the best tool to use :((

Comment: Please have a look at the solution provided (needed a bit of a distraction for a moment), generate in excel. While I would rather help teach folks how to use the tools and interpret, I hope that this helps. If it does, please feel free to accept it.

Comment: In R I'd use `read.table(stdin())` to read the data into a data frame, copy-pasting the data direct from this question (followed by return on a blank line to end data entry), then `lm` to fit the model (assigning to a model object), and then `predict` to get information at $x=100$ and - assuming that by "standard error" you mean residual standard error - `summary` on the fitted model object to get that. But the sequence of actions will be different for every tool you use, and there are many good tools available.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are asking this since you are new to the area. Here is a partial solution that should get you going in the correct direction with appropriate steps. I have used excel to do this, but could have used R, SAS, or many other tools.

**Step 1: Plot the data using a scatter plot**

[image]

As you can see, the graph shows that there appears to be some relationship between the $X$ and the $Y$ values. A formal hypothesis test could be done on the slope, but I have omitted that here.

**Step 2: Fit a regression model to the data of your choice**

You will see that I fit a simple linear regression model to the data, which has the equation $y = 1.3485x - 29.1166$. This means that, for every 1 unit increase in the $x$ value, the $y$ increases by 1.3485 units.

**Step 3: Calculate some coefficient of fit or determination.**

For this, I used the $R^2$ value, which was calculated to be 0.9193. This can be interpreted to mean that the variable $X$ explains approximately 91.93 percent of the variance of the $Y$ variable. Note that $0 \le R^2 \le 1$, where $1 =$ a perfect fit. Thus, the model that we have here fits quite well.

**Step 4: Make a prediction about the $Y$ value when the $X = 100$.**

Without adding comments about the obvious concerns relating to making a prediction outside the minima or maxima of a sample (within a regression context in particular), I note that you can easily do this by plugging $x = 100$ into the equation. Thus, you have:

$y = 1.3485 (100) - 29.116 = 105.74$

***NOTE: I did not calculate 95% confidence intervals, which likely would have been asked here. I also did not list out the standard error, which could have been generated using the data analysis toolkit in excel, or within the standard output in R. That said, I will leave you to figure out that step.***